# Receive text messages directly in the ios app

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, messaging, aws-pinpoint

I need my iOS app to read the text messages sent from an external device and perform certain tasks based on the received message without any major user intervention. I am totally aware that the content of received text messages cannot be automatically read from an iOS app. So I want to know is there any other ways possible where a text message can be converted into a push message and then sent it to the iOS app.

I need this to be implemented as reading text messages automatically and then perform accordingly without any user interaction is possible in the Android.

I need this to be implemented in the iOS app also if not exactly as the same as in the Android.

I've also heard about the services like twilio, nexmo, sinch, plivo etc. provide a similar feature. But I am not considering these as they are loaded with some heavy features and my use case is pretty minimal.

I just want a service which can convert received text messages to push notifications and then deliver it to the iOS devices.

Any help is much appreciable.

Comment: Do you want to update when the app is in background mode as well?

Comment: if the received push contains the "content-available" : 1" key, then the app can still process the push when it's in the background right? given the app is still in the memory.

Comment: This blog might help you 
https://medium.com/posts-from-emmerge/ios-push-notification-background-fetch-demystified-7090358bb66e

Comment: I think @MukulMore didn't quite get what I am looking for. I need to know about a service where I can convert text messages and send them as a push to ios devices. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Reading text messages is something even Android has deprecated with their new release and iOS has been very sure about it since the beginning. I don't think any other app can access your text messages even to convert to push notifications.

Comment: If the text message sent from an external device is being received at a service like twilio then twilio can forward those messages to our backend server and then we can receive those messages as push notifications on our iOS app. I am looking for a simple and reliable alternative method to twilio.

Comment: Ok! I guess I was on a different page.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're going to get more simple than the Twilio example you've just described there. Is there something else holding you back from that solution?